# Does there exist a closed non-orientable $2$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that it's complement is disconnected with $2$ components?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

So to give some context, in my physics class we were introduced to Gauss's law which states that for a closed orientable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the total flow through it is related to the electrical charge enclosed in it, by the formula: $$\epsilon_0 \Phi = q_{enc},$$
where $\epsilon_0$ is the permitivity constant of space.

So naturally I noticed that the orientability clause gives us access to notions such as inside and outside of the surface. But I started to wonder if such notions are meaningful for non-orientable surfaces embedded in higher dimensional spaces as well.

So I would like to know if (**Q1**) there exists a closed non-orientable $2$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that it's complement is disconnected with $2$ components, one bounded and the other, unbounded.

Since I suspect that higher codimension might ruin this notion altogether, (**Q2**) what happens if we drop the non-orientability requirement in (**Q1**)?

Comment: I have no formal argument at hand, but I find it unlikely that a 2-dimensional thing can separate 4-dimensional space. Morally the boundary of an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary should be of dimension $n-1$...

Comment: What you say is intuitively true for me but if we look at the complement of the surface as a manifold, then the surface itself will not be the boundary of it's complement in the techincal sense, as their union has no boundary as a manifold since it's just $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A smooth $2$-dimensional surface cannot separate $\mathbb{R}^4$ into two components. More precisely, one can apply the following result:

If $M\subset N$ is an a an embedded submanifold with $\operatorname{codim}M\ge 2$, and $N$ is connected, then $N\setminus M$ is also connected.

This result can be shown using [transversality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)). Essentially, given any smooth path $\gamma:[0,1]\to N$ between points $a,b\in N\setminus M$, we can always deform $\gamma$ very slightly to avoid any intersections with $M$. This means that any points connected by a path in $N$ are also connected by a path in $N\setminus M$.

Comment: Woah, this is what I wanted. Do you have a reference in mind for the result?

Comment: Also transversality is a notion defined for smooth manifolds. Does the same hold for topological manifolds as well?

Comment: Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology* and Lee's *Introduction to Smooth manifolds* are pretty standard references for transversality. While I suspect the result also holds for topological manifolds, I don't know of a proof.

Comment: In the topological category, the proof is Alexander duality.

Comment: @Kajelad, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MoshieKohan, although I don't even understand what the duality is really saying, but I take it that I have to study much more and see for myself later. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri: If you plan to study, say, QFT, there is a very good chance that you will learn homology and cohomology at some point. This is the machinery involved in duality theorems.